# Ambiguity about the Big-oh notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am currently trying to learn time complexity of algorithms, big-o notation and so on. However, some point confuses me a lot. I know that most of the time, the input size of an array or whatever we are dealing with determines the running time of the algorithm. Let's say I have an unsorted array with size `N` and I want to find the maximum element of this array without using any special algorithm. I just want to iterate over the array and find the maximum element. Since the size of my array is `N`, this process runs at `O(N)` or linear time. Let `M` is an integer that is the square root of `N`. So `N` can be written as the square of M that is `M*M` or `M^2`. So, I think there is nothing wrong if I want to replace `N` with `M^2`. I know that `M^2` is also the size of my array so my big-o notation could be written as `O(M^2)`. So, my new running time looks like running in quadratic time. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, if it happens to be that you have some variable `M` such that `M^2 ~= N` is always true, you could say the algorithm runs in `O(M^2)`.

But, note that now - the algorithm runs in **quadratic related to `M`**, and not quadratic time related to the input, it is still **linear related to the size of the input**.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is defining linear/quadratic, etc.

More precisely, you have to detail linear/quadratic, etc. with respect to something (N or M for your example). The most natural choice is to **study the complexity wrt. the size of the input** (N for your example).

Another trap for big integers is that the size of n is log(n). So for instance if you loop over all smaller integers, your algorithm is not polynomial.